# XML Data Source Connection in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xml, connection, visual-studio-2012, datasource

Is it possible to create an XML Data Source connection in Visual Studio 2012?  When I go to create a new connection for an XML database, I do not see any selection for an XML file.  All I see are the following:

Access, ODBC, SQL Server (3), and Oracle

Is it possible?

Comment: In my VS 2012 for Web ToolBox, I have XmlDataSource....but no Oracle.  BTW:  XmlDataSources are for files, not databases.

Comment: True, but there are limited choices in the "Data Sources Configuration Wizard".  I have Database, Service, Object, and Sharepoint as the choices.  File is not amongst the choices.  Database comes the closest.  You make me wonder if the choices presented are based on installed options in the Windows Control Panel.  For instance System.Data.Sqlite(.net) installs an option in Visual Studio for the designer component (will be in .83 this Nov. XX).