# Create XML data source in VS2012?

Tags: xml, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I would like to create an XML data source for a WPF project in VS2012.

In this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170361(v=vs.110).aspx), it says there should be (at least) two ways of creating an XML data source in VS2012 for WPF projects:  1) Drag an XML file onto the Data panel, and 2) Click "Create data source/Define New XML Data Source."

I create a new WPF application project.  Try the first method - I can't drop an XML file onto the data panel.  (I assume this means the "Data Sources" panel - right?)  Try the second method - when I "Add New Data Source", the only options given in the "Data Source Configuration Wizard" are "Database/Service/Object/SharePoint."  No XML option.

It looks this exact issue was raised in [XML Data Source Connection in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903643/xml-data-source-connection-in-visual-studio-2012) but never answered.  I also find absolutely nothing in MSDN.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you want to use this data? Just for design-time?

Comment: No, this is an application that will download a number (sometimes many) XML files each day, and the objective is to transfer the XML data to a SQL Server db.  Right now I'm looking for the best (i.e. easiest) way of parsing the XML files, and using them as XML data sources seemed a reasonable thing to look at.